# How to Mock a mongoose model from within a function

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai, sinon

I have this function that I want to test:

```
import { myModel } from '../models/myModel';
const myHandler = {
  async handleMessage(message) {
    try {
      console.log('Persisting data to database');
      await myModel.create({ status: 'OK', message });
      console.log('Payload stored successfully:');
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`Error trying to save to database: ${error}`);
      throw error;
    }
    return Promise.resolve([]);
  },
};
export default myHandler;
```

I want to test `handleMessage`  using `sinon` `mocha` and `chai`

```
import sinon from 'ts-sinon';
import { myHandler } from '../src/handlers';
import { myModel } from '../src/models/myModel';

describe('Handling Initial Message', () => {
  let createMessageStub: sinon.SinonStub;
  before(() => {
    createMessageStub = sinon.stub(myModel.prototype, 'save');
    createMessageStub.resolves({});
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    sinon.resetHistory();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    sinon.restore();
    createMessageStub.restore();
  });

  it('should work', async () => {
    const message = {...some object};
    await myHandler.handleMessage(message);
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(createMessageStub);

    const count = await myModel.countDocuments({});
    expect(count).to.equal(1);
  });
})
```

But I always get the error:

```
Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

using `done` doesnt work. I can see the logs, it stops at `persisting data to db` then the error occurs.
obs: I'm using `mongoose` from a package I imported within package.json.
it is not directly installed. It works when running the project, but cant make the mock to work.

Comment: Can you try to stub the `Model.create()` method?